# What response code do I need to send to notify client of using another request type?

Tags: httprequest

If I have script: **/only-post/save/some/object.php**.
If I it works only with **POST** requests. 
What response code and headers I must to give to client if he tries it with **GET** request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reply with a `405 Method Not Allowed`.

Also, you should return the following header in the response:

```
Allow: POST
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields (In the Response fields section - Allow).

Note that you may want to return `501 Not Implemented` if you intend to allow the received method in the future. In such case, you indicate the client the method is not implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like truth! :)

Answer (score 0):

- 405 - Method not allowed
- 501 - Not implemented
- 400 - Bad request

Make sure to send a message in the body (or header) of the response indicating the endpoint is post-only

Comment: Returning 400 Bad request is incorrect in such case since the request is valid but not supported.

Comment: That's why I was hesitant use one of those and gave a prefere to ask here.
Thanks again

Comment: If we are talking about PHP, the author is probably looking for `$_POST['variable']` that will not be set over a GET request.  Therefore, if the variable is not being set, it is a bad request.  With a 400 response, you would mention the missing variable and the acceptable method in the response body.